# I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 but there is not boot option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a notebook with win 8 (UEFI) on it so I decided to install ubuntu 14.04. I installed it on NOT UEFI mode I created 2 partitions a swap memory and then an ext4 and installed ubuntu everything fine. Now I am trying to boot into ubuntu but I can't 
When I turn on pc it boots automatically on windows 8 (no purple screen)
I go to BIOS but there is no option to to boot on ubuntu.

Pls tell me how to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean that you "installed it on NOT UEFI mode"?

Comment: You must reinstall it in UEFI mode. Otherwise, go to BIOS settings, disable secure boot, then change UEFI Mode to legacy/BIOS , in that case, you will able to boot UBUNTU but you will lose access to WIN8. Best solution for you to rEinstall Ubuntu 64 Bit. It is better than 32 bit, when it comes to compatibility with  systems with windows 8.

Comment: @Nattgew on the boot there were 2 options: UEFI and NOT UEFI(there is no written UEFI)